# How do you make an object in Scratch have horizontal momentum when you release dragging it?

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm trying to implement this in [Physica](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/506777077/), my Scratch-based physics engine. I tried adding it and the ball glitched out (couldn't move on the x axis at all). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You're never assigning anything to Xv, and in the "Touch" function you're never doing anything with the X-axis.  I don't think this is a glitch as much as missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a physics engine, then every object should have added variables for speed, and then you manipulate the speed:

To change the speed:

```
When ... (whenever your drag release is)
  set Vx to 10
```

this example has a drag function:
https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Draggable_Sprite_Feature

In the physics engine, speed constantly moves your object:

```
When green flag
forever
  add Vx to x
  add Vy to y
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how to sense drag releasing.

Comment: Example of drag on scratch wiki: https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Draggable_Sprite_Feature

Answer (score 0):

@boisvert pretty much answered your question. But if you want to sense drag releasing, use this code:

```
when green flag
set drag mode to draggable
forever
    wait until touching mouse pointer and mouse down
    wait until not mouse down
    point toward mouse pointer
    set V to distance to mouse pointer * 2
```

along with this:

```
when green flag
forever
    set V to V*0.9
    move V steps
    if on edge, bounce
```

It's not the most perfect code, but it will work

Example: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/558479500/